# Python coding convention "Wrong continued indentation before block: found by pylint

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

I used pylint to check my python code, and found this convention problem:

```
C:11, 0: Wrong continued indentation before block.
                    + this_time <= self.max):
                    ^   | (bad-continuation)
```

I tried to refine for times but the problem is still present, can someone help? Thanks!

```
if len(remaining_obj_list) > 0:
    for i in a_list:
        this_time = self.__get_time(i)
        for remaining_obj in remaining_obj_list:
            if (remaining_obj.get_time() # to fit 78 char rule
                + this_time <= self.max):
                i.append(remaining_obj)
                remaining_obj.set_used(True)
        if 0 == len(self.__get_unused_list):
            break
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Pylint doesn't want such continuation to start on the same column as the next indentation block. Also, notice that the message includes a hint on columns that it considers correct.

Comment: I never realized that the vertical bar is positioned as the hint for where it wants the indentation to be.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `+` on the previous line:

```
        if (remaining_obj.get_time() +
            this_time <= self.max):
```

As a side note though, you might want to consider the factors that are causing your code to have to fit within ~40 characters - perhaps you have a few too many indentation levels and your code could be refactored to have fewer nested blocks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator) the preferred place to break around a binary operator is **before** the operator.  This did not used to be the case, but it changed to be consistent with mathematical formula conventions.

Comment: PEP8 changed this recommendation, the preferred way is now to break *before* the operator.

Comment: This answer should be edited since it displays wrong information

Comment: @flornquake *Ewwwww*. (Actually, I'm not sure which is "better". Either can be more aesthetically pleasing or readable depending in the scenario...)

Comment: In real life I have always seen peopleputting operations like `a \n + b \n + c`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for spurious tabs (in Sublime: Ctrl + F, then enter a single space) and  replace them by the correct number of spaces. I had the same issue and while PyLint was complaining about line continuation, the error was actually triggered by misplaced tabs.

At indentations, PyLint seems to count spaces only and throws this error if the numbers don't add up to multiples of 4. Depending on the editor, misplaced tabs may not be immediately visible.